# Objective-C: Sqlite delete with multiple where clause

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to delete a row from my table. First I create the table with the createUserTable method. Now I want to delete a row - for example where userId = 4 and groupId = 5. I get false on the if statement inside remove row method. 
How do I fix this delete with multiple where?

```
+(BOOL)createUserTable:(sqlite3*)database{
    char* errormsg;

    NSString* sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ (%@ TEXT, %@ TEXT)",USER_GROUPS_TABLE,USER_ID,GROUP_ID];
    int res = sqlite3_exec(database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errormsg);
    if(res != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"ERROR: failed creating USERS-GROUPS table");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

+(void)addRow:(sqlite3*)database userId:(NSString*)userId groupId:(NSString*)groupId{
    NSLog(@"add Row: userId = %@ groupId = %@ in Sql", userId, groupId);
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;
    NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO %@ (%@,%@) values (?,?);",USER_GROUPS_TABLE,USER_ID,GROUP_ID];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String],-1,&statment,nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(statment, 1, [userId UTF8String],-1,NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statment, 2, [groupId UTF8String],-1,NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"addRow done");
            sqlite3_finalize(statment);
            return;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statment);
    NSLog(@"ERROR: addRowToTable failed %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

+(void)removeRow:(sqlite3*)database userId:(NSString*)userId groupId:(NSString*)groupId{
    NSLog(@"removeRow: userId = %@ groupId = %@ from Sql", userId, groupId);
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;
    NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ where US_ID = ? AND GR_ID = ?);",USER_GROUPS_TABLE];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String],-1,&statment,nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(statment, 1, [userId UTF8String],-1,NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statment, 2, [groupId UTF8String],-1,NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"removeRow done");
            sqlite3_finalize(statment);
            return;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statment);
    NSLog(@"ERROR: removeRowFromTable failed %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks (mostly) correct. What issue are you having?

Comment: FYI - you have the call to `sqlite3_finalize` in the wrong place. It should be called no matter what the result of `sqlite3_step` is.

Comment: @maddy the if statement return false, that means that the row isn't delete. I get remove row from table failed

Comment: @rmaddy fixed my code, i do finalize anyway

Comment: You should only call `sqlite3_finalize` if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds.

Comment: If the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails, you should have an `else` and in there you should log the result of `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Comment: How I do that??? I want to fix the delete statement, there is no reason to get failed on that. I added all my methods of this table. @rmaddy

Comment: If you add the call to `sqlite3_errmsg` when the prepare fails you will know why it is failing.

Comment: @rmaddy  Failed to delete row near ")": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I delete ")" before the ";"

```
NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ where US_ID = ? AND GR_ID = ?);",USER_GROUPS_TABLE];
```